# "NullPointerException in Salesforce Apex Trigger - Help Needed"

Tags: salesforce, apex

I'm facing an issue when trying to change the status of a Service Appointment to 'Complete' or 'Cannot Complete' within Salesforce. This action triggers the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jk7Z.png)

I've tried to change the Service Appointment status to 'Complete' or 'Cannot Complete' manually within Salesforce Classic. I expected this action to proceed without any issues, allowing me to update the status successfully.

However, when I make this change, I encountered a System.NullPointerException error with the message "FSL.TR001_Service_BeforeUpdate." This error is triggered by the custom Apex code in the SendServiceReport class, specifically within a trigger for the ServiceAppointment object. My expectation was that changing the status would not result in this error.

I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this error and allow the Service Appointment status change to occur without issues.

Here is my code:

APEX CLASS

```
public with sharing class SendServiceReport {
    @InvocableMethod(label='Send Service Report' description='Send Service Report')
    public static List<Boolean> sendEmail(List<String> serviceAppointmentIds) {
        if (serviceAppointmentIds.isEmpty()) return new List<Boolean>{false};

        String serviceAppointmentId = serviceAppointmentIds[0];
        System.debug('serviceAppointmentId: ' + serviceAppointmentId);
        // Consultar el ServiceAppointment y el contacto relacionado en una sola consulta
        ServiceAppointment service = [
            SELECT 
                Id, 
                ContactId, 
                Technician_Comments__c, 
                Customer_Comments__c, 
                Work_Performed__c, 
                Contact.Email,
                AppointmentNumber,
                Account.Name,
                AccountId
            FROM ServiceAppointment 
            WHERE Id = :serviceAppointmentId
        ];

        if (service == null) return new List<Boolean>{false};

        //Obtengo el contacto asociado al Service Appointment
        Contact contact = service.Contact;

        if (contact == null || String.isBlank(contact.Email)) return new List<Boolean>{false};

        //Creo el correo a traves del template
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        email.setToAddresses(new String[]{contact.Email});
        
        //Setteo el correo del remitente
        email.setTargetObjectId(service.ContactId);
        System.debug('service.ContactId: ' + service.ContactId);
        EmailTemplate emailTemplate = [
            SELECT Id, HtmlValue, DeveloperName
            FROM EmailTemplate 
            WHERE DeveloperName = 'Service_Report_Email_Template' 
            LIMIT 1
        ];

        if(emailTemplate == null) return new List<Boolean>{false};
        //Setteo el template del correo
        email.setTemplateId(emailTemplate.Id);
        System.debug('emailTemplate.Id: ' + emailTemplate.Id);
        //Setteo sobre que registro se va a enviar el correo
        email.setWhatId(service.Id);
        System.debug('service.Id: ' + service.Id);
        
        List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment> attachedServiceReport = new List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment>();

        //Consultar ContentDocumentLink relacionados con el ServiceAppointment
        List<ContentDocumentLink> contentDocumentLinks = [
            SELECT ContentDocumentId
            FROM ContentDocumentLink
            WHERE LinkedEntityId = :serviceAppointmentId
        ];

        Set<Id> contentDocumentIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (ContentDocumentLink cdl : contentDocumentLinks) {
            contentDocumentIds.add(cdl.ContentDocumentId);
        }

        //Consultar ContentVersion para obtener archivos adjuntos
        List<ContentVersion> contentVersions = [
            SELECT VersionData, FileType, Title
            FROM ContentVersion
            WHERE ContentDocumentId IN :contentDocumentIds
        ];
        
        //Variable para almacenar el contentType con lowerCase();
        String contentType;
        //Blob para los contentTypes
        Blob attBody;
        for (ContentVersion contentVersion : contentVersions) {
            Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
            attBody = contentVersion.VersionData;
            if(!contentVersion.Title.contains('.pdf') && contentVersion.FileType == 'PDF'){
                attachment.setFileName('Service_Report' + contentVersion.Title + '.pdf');
                contentType = 'pdf';
            }
            else if(!contentVersion.Title.contains('.jpg') && contentVersion.FileType == 'JPG'){
                attachment.setFileName('Image_' + contentVersion.Title + '.jpg');
                contentType = 'jpg';
            }
            else if(!contentVersion.Title.contains('.png') && contentVersion.FileType == 'PNG'){
                attachment.setFileName('Image_' + contentVersion.Title + '.png');
                contentType = 'png';
            }
            else {
                attachment.setFileName(contentVersion.Title);
                contentType = contentVersion.Title.substring(contentVersion.Title.length() - 3, contentVersion.Title.length());
            }
            attachment.setContentType('application/' + contentType);
            attachment.setInline(false);
            attachment.setBody(attBody);
            attachedServiceReport.add(attachment);
        }

        // Agregar los archivos adjuntos al correo electrónico
        email.setFileAttachments(attachedServiceReport);

        // Enviar el correo electrónico
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{email});

        return new List<Boolean>{true};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"FSL." means error comes from Field Service Lightning package. Hard to say, the code from managed package is hidden. Can be permissions issue (do you have FSL license, permission sets), could be bad data or sharing issues (maybe this user can't see something the code is fetching).

I don't think the code you posted has anything to do with the error. I don't see any update statements. (maybe you have updates somewhere else in flow that calls this code) Have you seen https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000qQ53JAAS/nullpointerexception-when-setting-the-status-of-serviceappointment-record-to-complete for example?

Enabling Debug Logging could help nail it down. The debug will be limited (hidden most of the code but for example it should show queries), this might be a hint to what's wrong. Does it fail on all records or just few?

You could contact SF support too, it's their paid extra package. They'd have access to better debugging and could tell whether it's bad data or something else.

Comment: No the flow just check if de SA have the necessary documents, but the flow  doesn't even start it's only when i try to change the status in SA to Complete i'm trying this as a System Admin, and i tried to debug logs but it doesn't show anything. i really don't know what's happening x.x